# How do I make a customized table from MySQL using UserControl and FlowLayoutPanel in VB.Net?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datatable, user-controls, flowlayoutpanel

Sorry, Newbie here. I want to create a custom table that generates the records on a scrollable FlowLayoutPanel from a MySQL database using UserControl and the For Each loop in VB.Net. I tried it myself but it only shows the last record I saved in the database out of three records. I know something is wrong with my For Each loop since it's my first time to use it.

```
 Private Sub NewDisplay()

    connect()

    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand
    Dim conn As New MySqlConnection("host=localhost;username=root;password=;database=Database")
    Dim Reader As MySqlDataReader

    MD = "SELECT * From users"
    cmd = New MySqlCommand(MD, con)
    connect()
    Reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
    While Reader.Read
         NewUserName = (Reader.Item("UserName").ToString)
         NewUserID = (Reader.Item("UserID").ToString)
    End While


    Query = NewUserName & " " & NewUserID
    Dim ListControl As EmployeeListControl = New EmployeeListControl
    For Each Items In Query
        ListControl.EmployeeName.Text = NewUserName
        ListControl.EmployeeID.Text = NewUserID
        FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(ListControl)
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: You need to create a `New EmployeeListControl()` in the `While Reader.Read (...)` loop, set its properties and add it to the `FlowLayoutPanel.Controls` collection.

Comment: Also, you need to `.Dispose()` of your `conn` and `cmd` objects and call `Reader.Close()`.

Comment: I'm sorry but how do I do the first step?

Comment: `While Reader.Read Dim listControl = New EmployeeListControl() listControl.EmployeeName.Text = Reader.Item("UserName")?.ToString() listControl.EmployeeID.Text = Reader.Item("UserID")?.ToString() FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(listControl) End While `. Remove the rest.

Comment: Oh wow it finally works! It's more efficient too. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Credits to Jimi

```
While Reader.Read 
Dim listControl = New EmployeeListControl() 
listControl.EmployeeName.Text = Reader.Item("UserName").ToString() 
listControl.EmployeeID.Text = Reader.Item("UserID").ToString() 
FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(listControl) 
End While
```